# Can I use two different messaging applications?

Tags: settings, customization, chat

When you have a new phone, before setting preferences, actions that have more than one application capable to fulfil that request, present you a popup with those applications for you to choose; for instance, if you receive an sms with a link and you tap on that link, a popup may appear with chrome and firefox for you to choose which application is going to open it and show the associated web page. That is an example of non set preferences.

I want to send messages to different people with different applications.

For instance, if I open contacts, choose person A and tap the envelop icon besides the phone icon, I'd like the system to show me popup with options of application to send the message with.

Or, I want to set a preference that program A handles messages to contact A and program B handles messages to person B.

Is that possible?

My phone is a Samsung Galaxy S4
Android version is 4.2.2

Comment: I don't see the reason for a downvote, a request to improve or change the question is much better.

Comment: Sorry when I rewrote the question I forgot to leave that part. I already updated the question again

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's possible to use two messaging programs in same time (like two browsers), but i don't think it's possible to one program handles messages from one person and other program handles for other person.

Comment: Well having a popup window each time will work for me. But I don't have any preference set and still when I try to send a message, there is no popup asking which application should handle it. Seems so far that the system only considers the default messaging application and not Gibberbot.